# failed building wheels for drizzlepac or stsci.convolve

Tags: astronomy, astropy

I typed `pip install drizzlepac` then an error occurred saying:

> Failed building wheels for drizzlepac

The whole process looked like this:

```
Collecting drizzlepac
  Using cached drizzlepac-1.1.16.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.tools in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from drizzlepac)
Collecting stsci.convolve (from drizzlepac)
  Using cached stsci.convolve-2.2.0.tar.gz
Collecting stsci.image (from drizzlepac)
Collecting stsci.imagemanip (from drizzlepac)
Collecting stsci.imagestats (from drizzlepac)
Collecting stsci.ndimage (from drizzlepac)
Collecting stsci.stimage (from drizzlepac)
Collecting nictools (from drizzlepac)
Collecting stwcs>=1.1.2 (from drizzlepac)
Collecting fitsblender>=0.2.2 (from drizzlepac)
Collecting astrolib.coords>=0.39.4 (from drizzlepac)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyfits>=3.1.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyfits-3.3-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg (from drizzlepac)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from drizzlepac)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.distutils in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from stsci.tools->drizzlepac)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg (from stsci.tools->drizzlepac)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): d2to1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from stsci.tools->drizzlepac)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): astropy>=0.3.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from stsci.tools->drizzlepac)
Collecting pywcs (from stwcs>=1.1.2->drizzlepac)
Building wheels for collected packages: drizzlepac, stsci.convolve
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for drizzlepac ... error
............
  Skipping optional fixer: buffer
  Skipping optional fixer: idioms
  Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  Can't parse docstring in build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/drizzlepac/tweakback.py line 106: TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
  Can't parse docstring in build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/drizzlepac/skytopix.py line 71: TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
  Can't parse docstring in build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/drizzlepac/pixtosky.py line 73: TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
  Can't parse docstring in build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/drizzlepac/pixtopix.py line 67: TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
  Can't parse docstring in build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/drizzlepac/pixtopix.py line 78: TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
  Can't parse docstring in build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/drizzlepac/pixtopix.py line 88: TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
  running build_ext
  error: cannot find hook pywcs.hooks.setup: pywcs.hooks.setup

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for drizzlepac
```

And then it continued with `failed building wheel for stsci.convolve`.

So any ideas on where it went wrong? I'm nearly mad at this...

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.  Manually install `pywcs` first and it should work.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work...

Failed building wheel for drizzlepac
Failed building wheel for stsci.convolve

Comment: Oh, I see now you're installing on Python 3.5.  Several of these packages don't support Python 3, much less 3.5 yet.

Comment: OMG, that's surprising... Thanks for telling me!